# Will calling dataframe.distinct() result in shuffling the contents to the driver for a final distinction?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

I have the following code which tries to read some jsons, distinct them and write the output to a single json file. My question is if I should `.collect()` after the `.distinct()` or it will happen behind the scenes anyway?

```
val manyJsons = sqlContext.read.json(someJsonDirectory)
val distinctJsons = manyJsons.distinct()
distinctJsons.coalesce(1).write.json(jsonDirectoryWithOneFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing to a file in disk, you don't need a `.collect()`

`.distinct()` will `shuffle` the data to find `duplicates` and `remove duplicates`.

`.coalesce(1)` in your code is moving all of the `partitions` to one node before writing to a file. This is equivaluent to `.collect(`). The only difference is that `.collect()` will move all the partitions to the `driver node` but `.coalesce` may or may not move all partition to `driver node`. `.coalesce(1)` is for creating one partition so that output file is only one.